# javascript, passing parameters to a callback inside a closure that is inside a function

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, closures

I'm stuck with a problem related to db.transaction().objectStore.onsuccess
i need to get back the data to create a table with the results.

As first test, i try to return data from the call after the cursor has been read completely:

```
function readAll() {
  var resultData=[];
  var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event, args) {                          
    var cursor = event.target.result;               
    if (cursor){
        resultData.push(cursor.value);                  
        cursor.continue();
    }else{
       return resultData;
            }             
 };
}
```

but this doesn't work because the asynchronous nature of the indexedDB

so, after some thinking i try to use a callback...

```
function readAll(callBackFunction) {
  var resultData=[];
  var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event, args) {                          
    var cursor = event.target.result;               
    if (cursor){
        resultData.push(cursor.value);                  
        cursor.continue();
    }else{
        callBackFunction;
    }             
 };
}
```

this seem partially work because the callback will be called but I'm not able to pass parameters to the callback function because parameters array is empty inside the onsuccess=function()  (as i can understand parameters are bind to readAll function) and I'm not able to pass it inside the onsuccess.
So how can i pass parameters to callback?

There is another option different from the callback?

thank you

**UPDATE**

My problem is that i need to pass more parameters other than the result, like "table_id", "header" etc. so i need to pass some parameters to readAll and pass those parameters to callback, something like:
readAll(callBackFunction, "table_id", "header_array")

I've already tested below solution that doesn't work:

```
function readAll(callBackFunction) {
  var resultData=[];
  var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event, args) {                          
    var cursor = event.target.result;               
    if (cursor){
        resultData.push(cursor.value);                  
        cursor.continue();
    }else{
        callBackFunction(parameters[1], parameters[2], resultData);
    }             
 };
}

readAll(createTable, 'table_id', ['username', 'email']);
```

the problem is that the parameters array is empty inside the closure

**UPDATE 2**

arguments array is empty inside the closure but is ok outside. If i move the callback outside the closure, I've have parameters but not data..

**UPDATE 3**

Also adding all parameters to function seem not working.

```
    function readAll(callback, header, idName, classToAdd, resultData) {
                    var resultData=[];
                    var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
                        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {                          
                    var cursor = event.target.result;               
                    if (cursor){
                        resultData.push(cursor.value);
                        //alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + ", Age: " + cursor.value.age + ", Email: " + cursor.value.email);
                        cursor.continue();
                    }else{
//HERE ALL ARGUMENTS ARE EMPTY BUT resultData Exists!

                     callback(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], resultData);
                    }             
               };
//HERE ALL ARGUMENTS EXISTS EXCEPT resultData!
                     callback(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], resultData);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some time I'm back to this problem and find a solution that work.
The problem is that I initialize the objectStore in a single call.

```
var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
```

if I divide this call in two different pieces:

```
var transaction = db.transaction("employee");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("employee");
```

everything work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could just invoke the function like

```
callBackFunction(resultData);
```

so that the function you passed receive the results. In the function declaration you should have such a parameter:

```
function callbackFunction(results) { 
   //create the table
}
```

You would pass it to `readAll()` like

```
readAll(callbackFunction);
```

**EDIT:**

According to your edit.
You have to add extra parameters to your function declaration

```
function readAll(callBackFunction, table_id, data) {
   // ... code
  callBackFunction(table_id, data, resultData);
}
```

Then you can declare 2 more parameters in your createTable function and they will receive "table_id" and "data".

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that i need to pass more parameters, like "table_id", "header" etc. so i need to pass some parameters to readAll and pass those parameters to callback, something like:
readAll(callBackFunction, "table_id", "header_array")

Comment: I did this test also but the arguments array is empty inside the closure

Comment: @Marco, my bad, forgot you call your function within a different function, so the arguments object is different. You must choose the second solution with extra parameters added to readAll. (it's described above)

Comment: but the problem is that:
objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
 console.log(arguments);
}

return undefined! only outside the function the arguments are correct

Comment: @Marco, read my post. You must add `readAll(callBackFunction, table_id, data) {` and then call  `callBackFunction(table_id, data, resultData);` within that function. If you wanted to store arguments, you could create an array and fill it with arguments ' values. However, I would create such a function as described above and in my edited code.

Comment: Sorry but probably I can't understand what you mean :( i add another update to my post.. i hope that now my problem is more clear thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @Marco, call  `callback(header, idName, classToAdd, resultData);` The argument object is different within "onsuccess" callback.